# Different independent variables and table from summary-values

Tags: r

I have problem that I have been trying to solve for a couple of hours now but I simply can't figure it out (I'm new to R btw..).

Basically, what I'm trying to do (using mtcars to illustrate) is to make R test different independent variables (while adjusting for "cyl" and "disp") for the same independent variable ("mpg"). The best soloution I have been able to come up with is:

```
lm <- lapply(mtcars[,4:6], function(x) lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + x, data = mtcars))
summary <- lapply(lm, summary)
```

... where 4:6 corresponds to columns "hp", "drat" and "wt".

This acutually works OK but the problem is that the summary appers with an "x" instead of for instace "hp":

```
$hp

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + x, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0889 -2.0845 -0.7745  1.3972  6.9183 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 34.18492    2.59078  13.195 1.54e-13 ***
cyl         -1.22742    0.79728  -1.540   0.1349    
disp        -0.01884    0.01040  -1.811   0.0809 .  
x           -0.01468    0.01465  -1.002   0.3250    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.055 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7679,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
F-statistic: 30.88 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 5.054e-09
```

*Questions:*

Is there a way to fix this? And have I done this in the smartest way using lapply, or would it be better to use for instance for loops or other options?

Ideally, I would also very much like to make a table showing for instance only the estimae and P-value for each dependent variable. Can this somehow be done?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

One approach to get the name of the variable displayed in the summary is by looping over the names of the variables and setting up the formula using `paste` and `as.formula`:

```r
lm <- lapply(names(mtcars)[4:6], function(x) { 
  formula <- as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ cyl + disp + ", x))
  lm(formula, data = mtcars)
})
summary <- lapply(lm, summary)
summary
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = formula, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.0889 -2.0845 -0.7745  1.3972  6.9183 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 34.18492    2.59078  13.195 1.54e-13 ***
#> cyl         -1.22742    0.79728  -1.540   0.1349    
#> disp        -0.01884    0.01040  -1.811   0.0809 .  
#> hp          -0.01468    0.01465  -1.002   0.3250    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.055 on 28 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7679, Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
#> F-statistic: 30.88 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 5.054e-09
```

Concerning the second part of your question. One way to achieve this by making use of `broom::tidy` from the `broom` package which gives you a summary of regression results as a tidy dataframe:

```r
lapply(lm, broom::tidy)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  34.2       2.59       13.2  1.54e-13
#> 2 cyl          -1.23      0.797      -1.54 1.35e- 1
#> 3 disp         -0.0188    0.0104     -1.81 8.09e- 2
#> 4 hp           -0.0147    0.0147     -1.00 3.25e- 1
```

Comment: there is a baseR way to get the `broom::tidy` tibble `lapply(summary, function(x) x$coefficients)`

Answer (score 0):

We could use `reformulate` to create the formula for the `lm`

```
lst1 <- lapply(names(mtcars)[4:6], function(x) {
    fmla <- reformulate(c("cyl", "disp", x), 
       response = "mpg")
    model <- lm(fmla, data = mtcars)
     model$call <- deparse(fmla)
     model
       })
```

Then, get the `summary`

```
summary1 <- lapply(lst1, summary)
summary1[[1]]

#Call:
#"mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp"

#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-4.0889 -2.0845 -0.7745  1.3972  6.9183 

#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) 34.18492    2.59078  13.195 1.54e-13 ***
#cyl         -1.22742    0.79728  -1.540   0.1349    
#disp        -0.01884    0.01040  -1.811   0.0809 .  
#hp          -0.01468    0.01465  -1.002   0.3250    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 3.055 on 28 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.7679,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
#F-statistic: 30.88 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 5.054e-09
```